# how to check in the tex file an argument has been passed to a class

Tags: optional-arguments

within a tex file, I'd like to know if a given argument has been passed to a class. E.g., suppose in my main tex file:

> \documentclass[optionA]{myClass}

How can I check if `optionA` has been passed to `myClass` ? And is there a way to know its value / type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\@ifclasswith{myClass}{optionA}{yes}{no}
```

In the standard option processing code, options are just names, they never have a "value".